# Formating string as money while typing

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox where I'm suposed to type the value/price of a certain product.
It's already on the `TextBox_KeyUp` event. What I need is how may convert the decimal while I'm typing?

I have this:

```
 string Currency = string.Format("{0:#.00}", Convert.ToDecimal(Txt_Vl_Total.Text));
```

but it does not allow decimal (cents);

I want to type only the numbers, without needing to use the comma `,`. I want the software put the comma for me.

Comment: I think you'll need to explain the logic behind your conversions.

Comment: Do you want to change the value in the textbox as the user is typing? That sounds messy. You could show it in a label instead?

Comment: Web, Window forms, WPF?

Comment: @Blorgbeard instead the user have to type `125,50`, I want that the software do that for the user, you know ?

Comment: Your conversions are inconsistent!

Comment: @Abbas tried to be more clear, please check this out.

Comment: Try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183783%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229644%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Do not use textbox for that.
Try use NumericTextBox.
Good explanation:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183783%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: If the user presses the keys `1`,`2`,`3`, do you think they mean `1,23`, `12,30`, or `123,00`?

Comment: If you assume the user will always type all the digits including two after the `,`, then you can just divide by 100 and format as decimal.

Comment: @Blorgbeard I want it to be 1,23, as the user type, it pushes the number to the right `<-`. `1` + `2` + `3` = `1,23`. `1` + `2` + `3` + `4` = `123,40`

Comment: Why is it `123,40` and not `12,34`? How would the user type `12,34` then?

Comment: @Blorgbeard gee you're right... Feeling so dumb now. SO All I need to do is what you said before? /100 and convert to decimal ?

Comment: I think so! Try doing that. `decimal.Parse`, then `/ 100M` then `string.Format` like before.

Comment: But again, I wouldn't try changing the text *in the textbox* while the user is typing - you will lose the user's cursor position, etc.

Comment: @Blorgbeard what do you suggest me ? But then the use would have to type the comma `,`, right ? ;s

Comment: I would suggest you format the value either (1) as the user types, but put the result into a label, not the textbox; or (2) format the text-box, but only when the user finishes typing (say, the OnExit event).

Comment: @Blorgbeard I'm just blowing my mind with the comma `,´. How could make the software insert the comma without change it while the user types =x